# Studying in Non-Muslim Environment

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim-countries

Is it allowed to to travel from an islamic country to a non-muslim country where the majority are non-muslims (e.g. UK, USA) for the sake of studying?

**(From Sunni's point of view)**

Comment: Yes why not. Why do you think it is not allowed? Could you write your suspicions etc.?

Comment: I mean like, at universities most girls are barely dressed and it's all messed up. And seeing stuff like that tempt a person normally. And with time, seeing wrong stuff which aren't wrong to them will be normal and normal until you won't see it as wrong. In addition, there are very few people to encourage you as a muslim to stick to the right path. So wouldn't going there be like a gate to fitna?

Comment: hmmmm. Sounds a good point. But I will say what use is of that eeman which gets washed away with small events like these! And by the way, accidentally looking at some woman is not a sin but looking at a woman again and again and with some bad intention is a sin. If you are a good Muslim then you can keep your belief up and high.. And to be frank, it really depends on you.

Comment: You got a point, but no matter how a person has high eeman and good beliefs, he shouldn't be certain he'll be safe from fitna. It is human nature that  he adapts to the environment he is exposed to. Abo Bakr al Seddiq radiya Allahu a'nhu said something which means: If one of my legs was in Jannah and other was out, i will still be unsure and uncertain of entering it.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it's unclear whether you are looking for an answer from a Shia or Sunni perspective. From the accepted answer, it seems you are asking as a Sunni. But we can't be sure until you let us know! Please edit to clarify and we should be able to reopen.

Comment: @JonEricson questions that are for both shia and sunni are allowed, see islam meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no restrictions on where you can study (or live). The only restriction there is, is that if you are living in an oppressed regime which do not allow you to practice your religion, you then should move out of that place. As Allah says in the Quran:

[image]

> Indeed, those whom the angels take [in death] while wronging themselves - [the angels] will say, "In what [condition] were you?" They will say, "We were oppressed in the land." The angels will say, "Was not the earth of Allah spacious [enough] for you to emigrate therein?" For those, their refuge is Hell - and evil it is as a destination. [4:97]

Since countries like the UK, USA allow religious liberties (even Islamically speaking, much more than Islamic/Arabic countries).

The fact that there are many woman dressed badly in the Summer in schools, I doubt countries like many northern African countries are any different. It is up to you to lower your gaze. However, if you feel that you are yourself a weak person who can not handle being around people who are different, or easily impressionable or weak willed, you might want to stay in your country if you think it might negatively effect you.

Each person is different. I know many people who came to the US from third world countries, studied, thrived and some became rich and were able to hold on to their Muslim identity with a strong Muslim family. Some even hold on to their old traditions (from their countries) dress wise and social wise.

Comment: Good! So, in short, only if one is confident that he can control himself, he should think of going to that country. Even if he goes there, whenever he feels like he is going off track, he should immediately leave. Peace!